# Difference between weak AI and strong AI?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

can you please explain me both terms and what are the major differences?

How can you determine whether an intelligence is weak or strong?

Why these terms?

Comment: Just a note, this question is probably more suited for [CrossValdiated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [ComputerScience](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: this is not suitable for CrossValidated, no. This is way too broad for Computer Science.

Answer (score 1):

> **Q**: How can you determine whether an intelligence is weak or strong?

**A**: There is no strong AI in existence (yet). Therefore everything is *weak AI* or less.

**Explanation** from [here](http://waitbutwhy.com/2015/01/artificial-intelligence-revolution-1.html):

> Artificial Narrow Intelligence (ANI): Sometimes referred to as **Weak
>   AI**, Artificial Narrow Intelligence is AI that specializes in one area.
>   There’s AI that can beat the world chess champion in chess, but that’s
>   the only thing it does. Ask it to figure out a better way to store
>   data on a hard drive, and it’ll look at you blankly.

And

> Artificial General Intelligence (AGI): Sometimes referred to as **Strong
>   AI**, or Human-Level AI, Artificial General Intelligence refers to a
>   computer that is as smart as a human across the board—a machine that
>   can perform any intellectual task that a human being can. Creating AGI
>   is a much harder task than creating ANI, and we’re yet to do it.
>   Professor Linda Gottfredson describes intelligence as “a very general
>   mental capability that, among other things, involves the ability to
>   reason, plan, solve problems, think abstractly, comprehend complex
>   ideas, learn quickly, and learn from experience.” AGI would be able to
>   do all of those things as easily as you can.

Both are AI, but one is for single purpose only, so it is regarded as less *powerful*, hence the term *weak*. The other is Human level AI, so it is called *strong*.

But the terminology does not stop here. You also have *Artificial Superintelligence*, which is even better than Human AI:

> Artificial Superintelligence (ASI): Oxford philosopher and leading AI
>   thinker Nick Bostrom defines superintelligence as “an intellect that
>   is much smarter than the best human brains in practically every field,
>   including scientific creativity, general wisdom and social skills.”
>   Artificial Superintelligence ranges from a computer that’s just a
>   little smarter than a human to one that’s trillions of times
>   smarter—across the board.

Comment: I loved that article from waitbutwhy, he's now writing a series of posts on Elon Musk's work, have a look too.